# Cannot create image from getResourceAsStream() in JavaFX projects

Tags: java, image, url, javafx

I cannot create an image in any of my JavaFX projects using the following kind of code:

```
final String url = "line.jpg"; 
Image image = new Image(Config.class.getResourceAsStream(url));
```

because there is always a null pointer exception pointing to the second line. Obviously, I have checked that the image file is in the correct directory. I have tried example programs, some directly copied from these boards, but these also fail for the same reason.

I suspect I lack a resource in Netbeans or JavaFX but I can't figure out what is missing.

Comment: What do you think the "correct directory" is?

Comment: Your java-code should sit below `src/main/java/<package>`-folder, and your jpg should be stored in `src/main/resources/<package>`, please make sure your package-folder is the same as your Config-class

Comment: Please open your JAR file with a ZIP tool and double-check "line.jpg" is in the same directory as Config.class.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any tool in Win 8.1 that can unzip jar files.

Comment: I don't appear to have a Config.class file. How does one get one of these?

Comment: Is this the correct library to get the Config class?                                              import jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.regexp.joni.Config;

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround appears to be to include the image file in a css stylesheet and link it to the program by setting the gui components id like this:

```
Button homeButton = new Button();
homeButton.setId("homebutton");
```

In the stylesheet there is:

```
#homebutton {
-fx-background-image: url("images/homebtn.jpg");
-fx-pref-width: 30;
-fx-pref-height: 30;
}
```

Its not ideal being forced into this solution and Swing seems far better at dealing with image files. I assume a bug in JavaFX that always causes the following to fail:

```
Image image = new Image(Config.class.getResourceAsStream(url));
```